# Using email-template-v2 nodejs dynamic content not display

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, nodemailer, email-templates

I have use `email-template-v2` in nodejs when i send dynamic data onto template its not display dynamic content  its only display variable

code is here

```
var template = new EmailTemplate(templateDir)
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: '***@***.com',
    pass: '*******'
  }
});
var locals = {
    userName: "XYZ" //dynamic data for bind into the template
};


template.render(locals, function (err, temp) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error", err);

    } else {
        transporter.sendMail({
      from: '****',
      to: "*****@gmail.com",
      html:  temp.html,
      text:  temp.text,
      subject:  temp.subject,
    }, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);

    })

  }

})
```

> temp.html file code

```
<html>

    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin:0 auto;max-width:600px;">
            <p>Hi,{userName}</br>
        How are you It's testing mail
        </br></br>
        Thanks
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and email ouput was like this

```
Hi,{userName} How are you It's testing mail Thanks
```

and i want this

```
Hi,XYZ How are you It's testing mail Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely try this effective approach for any number of variables in your locals JSON Object to get replaced:

1. Use this format in the template for the variables you want to replace:

   Hi, ${userName} in your case, for example.
2. Get the template(template.html in your case) from wherever it is stored (in my case I get it from the database) and store it temporarily in a variable, say, emailTemplate.
3. Then pass template(emailTemplate) and the json with all variables you want to 
   replace(locals) to modifyTemplate function:

   let modifiedTemplate = this.modifyTemplate(emailTemplate, locals);
4. Define modifyTemplate function this way:

   ```
   modifyTemplate: function (tpl, args) {
     var keys = Object.keys(args),
        fn = new Function(...keys,
           'return `' + tpl.replace(/`/g, '\\`') + '`');
     return fn(...keys.map(x => args[x]));
   }
   ```
5. You will have the template now replaced with your values in modifiedTemplate variable.

Comment: i cant understand your code ..! thanks for replay:-)

Comment: @khushboo Mulani, Can you once explain me the modify template code. What are you replacing there. the whole HTML?

Answer (score 0):

i found it

I have used `<% %>` instead of `{}`

and its work

i use this

```
<%= userName%>;
```